# Issue in custom pagination

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, pagination

I have written code like

```
          protected void lnkprev_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        List<ListItem> pages = new List<ListItem>();
        int pagecount = Convert.ToInt32(Session["pagecount"].ToString());
        int lastnumber = Convert.ToInt32(Session["lastnumber"].ToString());
        int prevtennumber = lastnumber - 10;
        for (int i=prevtennumber ; i <= pagecount; i++)
        {
            if (i < prevtennumber)
            {
                pages.Add(new ListItem(i.ToString(), i.ToString(), i != PageIndex));
                if (i == 1)
                {
                    lnkprev.Visible = false;
                }
            }
            Session["lastnumber"] = prevtennumber;
            Session["pagecount"] = pagecount;
            rptPager.DataSource = pages;
            rptPager.DataBind();
        }
     }

    protected void lnknext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<ListItem> pages = new List<ListItem>();
        int pagecount = Convert.ToInt32(Session["pagecount"].ToString());
        int lastnumber = Convert.ToInt32(Session["lastnumber"].ToString());
        int nexttennumber = lastnumber + 10;
        for (int i = lastnumber; i <= pagecount; i++)
        {
            if (i < nexttennumber)
            {
                pages.Add(new ListItem(i.ToString(), i.ToString(), i != PageIndex));
                if (i == pagecount)
                {
                    lnknext.Visible = false;
                }
           }
            Session["lastnumber"] = nexttennumber;
            Session["pagecount"] = pagecount;
            rptPager.DataSource = pages;
            rptPager.DataBind();
        }
    }
```

I am populating repeater with page number which is used for pagination in grid view. Actually I have to show first ten numbers at first. when user will click on next button, then the page numbers should start from 10 to 20 and so on. 
Now the next button is working fine. The prev button is not working properly.
Please help !!!

Comment: this is a bad design to making paging - do you save on session the next page, the page number and all that ? do you even think that a user can open more than one page at the same time.

Comment: yes you are right!!!  do i have store them in cookies

Comment: the cookies are worst, and the same as session - You save it on the url it self with parametres

Comment: Are there any other methods, it is very difficult for us to use url. since the pagination control is used through out the project

Comment: you have only 2 options - either post either get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well apart from other remarks (I think there's a code rewriting work to do)

```
for (int i=prevtennumber ; i <= pagecount; i++)
        {
            //this will never be reached, as you start with i = prevtennumber
            if (i < prevtennumber)
```

So I would say at least (or any logical thing else than prevtennumber)

```
if (i < lastnumber)
```

Answer (score 1):

When you're debugging your code, the first thing to do is to **try to make your job easier**.

Let's do a quick refactoingr of your `next()` function and see what's wrong when you copy/paste your code like you did here. Feel free to correct any writing mistake i could have done here, depending on specifics of your view.

```
 protected void CreatePages(int startingPoint, int checkingPoint, int endPoint, Button button)
        {
            List<ListItem> pages = new List<ListItem>();
            for (i = startingPoint; i < endPoint; i++)
            {
            if (i < checkingPoint)
            {
                pages.Add(new ListItem(i.ToString(), i.ToString(), i != PageIndex));
                if (i == endPoint)
                {
                    button.Visible = false;
                }
           }
            }
            Session["lastnumber"] = checkingPoint;
            Session["pagecount"] = endPoint;
            rptPager.DataSource = pages;
            rptPager.DataBind();
            }

   protected void lnknext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int pagecount = Convert.ToInt32(Session["pagecount"].ToString());
        int lastnumber = Convert.ToInt32(Session["lastnumber"].ToString());
        int nexttennumber = lastnumber + 10;
        CreatePagesAndBindRepeater(lastnumber, nexttennumber, pagecount, lnknext);
        }
```

Now, what you actually did for your `prev()` is :

```
         protected void lnkprev_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    int pagecount = Convert.ToInt32(Session["pagecount"].ToString());
    int lastnumber = Convert.ToInt32(Session["lastnumber"].ToString());
    int prevtennumber = lastnumber - 10;
    CreatePagesAndBindRepeater(lastnumber, prevtennumber, pagecount, lnkprev);
     }
```

Which is wrong; you're iterating forward in this function, **not backwards**, making your checks not working, causing you all the trouble you're facing. In this case, setting the incrementation of your iterator would allow you to do both behaviours in a working way (Raphaël Althaus points out the main flaw)

---

In any case, using session to record navigation data is troublesome, for many reasons (Coockie deleted during navigation, timeout, forcing state tracking in your server ...)

You should use Request data instead, and bind your repeater accordingly with each request you're getting.